# Prove that a matrix and its inverse are over the same field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be some matrix over $\mathbb{Q}$ (then it's also over
>   $\mathbb{R}$). Suppose $A$ is invertible over $\mathbb{R}$ (that is,
>   $A^{-1}$ is over $\mathbb{R}$). Prove that $A^{-1}$ is also over
>   $\mathbb{Q}$.

I know that I have to prove that $A^{-1}$ contains no irrational numbers but I fail to do so. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that the elements of $A$ are all rational numbers? Is that implied by the expression "some matrix over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Mico - It just means that $A$ doesn't have irrational numbers.

Comment: @user191052 "Doesn't have irrational numbers" is the same as "Has only rational numbers".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate an inverse of a matrix in multiple ways. (Adjuncts, extend it with identity matrix and Gauss eleminate it, LUP decompositions,...). But in the end, all you will be doing is taking sums and products of fractions so the outcomes can never be irrational. (Sum or products of fractions will still be fractions)

Comment: Intuitively, I understand it. I just wanted a more formal proof. But thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is an invertible matrix with entries in $ℚ$, what two things can you say about its determinant? Think of [Cramer's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule#Finding_inverse_matrix).

Comment: Yes, I thought about determinants. In particular, we know that if $A$ is invertible then $\det{A} \neq 0$ and also $\det{A} \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then $\det{A^{-1}}=\frac{1}{\det{A}}$. Thus $\det{A^{-1}} \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $A^{-1}$ is over $\mathbb{Q}$. However I'm not sure about this proof. Or is it correct?

Comment: @user131052: $\det(A^{-1})\in\mathbb Q$ does not imply $A^{-1}$ is over $\mathbb Q$. Take $\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt 2 & 0\\ 0 & \sqrt 2\end{pmatrix}$ for $A^{-1}$, for example. What k.stm suggests is to use this fact together with Cramer's formula for inverses.

Comment: @rosebud - so basically what you mean is that because $\frac{1}{\det(A)} \in \mathbb Q$ and because $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ is over $\mathbb Q$ then $A^{-1}$ is over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @user191052 Yes. This also generalizes to arbitrary rings.

Comment: @k.stm: To arbitrary _commutative_ rings.

Answer (score 2):

I think finding inverse of a matrix by adjoint method gives the answer to your question; because determinant function  takes values in the field of rational functions and the adjoint of a matrix also takes values in the field of rational numbers( while we are computing the adjoint of a matrix, we just multiply and add the elements in the field of rational numbers that is we do computations in a field so the adjoint of a matrix (over the field of rational numbers)  will be a matrix over the field of rational numbers.)